# Django: Count() in multiple annotate()

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project with `ForumPost`, `ForumComment`, `ForumPostLike`, `ForumCommentLike` models. Post has multiple comments, multiple forumpostlikes. 
Comment has multiple forumcommentlikes. Each user can only like a post or a comment once.

**What I want:** I want to order posts by `calculated = (num_comments*5 + num_postlikes + num_commentlikes)`

**Questions:** With the following code, It seems that I am getting what I wanted. But there are some weird behaviors of `Count()`. Also, I would like to know if there is a better way of achieving my goal.

**models.py**

```
class ForumPost(models.Model):
      # author, title .. etc.

class ForumComment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(ForumPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    #other fields

class ForumPostLike(models.Model):
    liker = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='liked_forumposts')
    post = models.ForeignKey(ForumPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='forumpostlikes')

class ForumCommentLike(models.Model):
    liker = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='liked_forumcomments')
    comment = models.ForeignKey(ForumComment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='forumcommentlikes')
```

**views.py**

```
posts= ForumPost.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).\
        prefetch_related('comments', 'forumpostlikes')

posts_top = posts\
        .annotate(num_commentlikes=Count('comments__forumcommentlikes__liker'))\
        .annotate(num_postlikes=Count('forumpostlikes', distinct=True))\
            .annotate(num_comments=Count('comments', distinct=True))\
                    .annotate(calculated=(F('num_comments')*Value(5)) + F('num_postlikes') +F('num_commentlikes')*Value(0.5))\
                    .order_by('-calculated')
```

**Weird behavior of Count():**
`annotate(num_commentlikes=Count('comments__forumcommentlikes__liker'))` 
using this code, I wanted to get the total number of likes from all comments associated with the current post. But the result shows **2*correct number**. Once I realized this, I multiplied this number with `Value(0.5)` to reflect correct number.

If I use distinct as follow:
`annotate(num_commentlikes=Count('comments__forumcommentlikes__liker', distinct=True))`
this code only gives me the number of likes from the first comment.

Why is this happening? Also, how to improve my code? Thanks!

Comment: Because you join on `forumpostlikes` as well, so that will act as a "multiplier". You need to divide the `num_commentlikes` by the number of `forumpostlikes`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you so much! ```+(F('num_commentlikes')/F('num_postlikes'))``` worked!